# Reusing models between views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm relatively new to MVC development and I'm confused how on how to organize my Models and Views.

I'm building a "register" form that is also reused as an "update profile" form.  The Password field is required for registering, but not for the "update profile" form, so I'm just excluding the Password field.

In my Controller, I'm reusing the Register ActionResult and just passing in a flag whether it's an update or insert:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(MyModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        if (model.IsUpdate)
        {
            //update
        }
        else
        {
            //insert
        }
     }
```

However, for the "update profile" form, it's always going to be invalid because the Password field is never set.  I know I can create two Models and two Controller Actions, one for the registration and one for updating the profile, but it seems like duplicating a lot of code, or maybe that's just how it has to be done.

Comment: why is it a problem, when password is not set?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt because in my model, I have the "Required" Attribute set on that Password property

Comment: That's how it should be done. You have 2 different views serving 2 different purposes so it should be 2 different view models.

Comment: I usually use ViewModels... so I would create RegisterViewModel, and UpdateProfileViewModel... both are wrappers around model, in one password is required in another no... and also you would have to create two actions yes... but the logic is different, so going with separate views are ok

Comment: @ArsenMkrt So are you saying create a model with the properties that are shared between the views, such as "First Name", "Last Name", etc. then put the Password property in the two ViewModels?

Comment: for example, given you are reading model from db, let's name it RegisterInfo... and there is UserName, Password and etc... so you can remove data attributes from this class, create two wrapper viewmodels, that takes this class as constructor argument... and create corresponding properties inside this viewmodels, that delegates to RegisterInfo properties... so get{return regInfo.prop} set{regInfo.prop = vlaue}